# ORA-00904: "ACCUMDEPR": invalid identifier / select query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm rather new to writing sql code and I'm getting an invalid indentifier when I try to run the following code.  I'm wondering if the fields I'm trying to sum are causing me an issue.

I'm trying to get 1 record where the depr and accumdepr fields have been added together

I'd also like to know if there are any resources you could suggest that would help me become more knolwedgeable about this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.....

```
SELECT pa.BUSINESS_UNIT as bu,
pc.DEPTID as deptid,
pa.ASSET_ID as assetnumber,
pa.DESCR as descr,
pa.IN_SERVICE_DT as inservdate,
pc.COST as assetcost,
pb.METHOD as deprecmeth,
pb.LIFE as assetlife,
Sum(pdr.DEPR) as depr,
Sum(pdr.DEPR_YTD) as accumdepr
from PS_ASSET pa
inner join PS_COST pc on pc.ASSET_ID = pa.ASSET_ID
inner join PS_BOOK pb on pb.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID
inner join PS_DEPR_RPT pdr on pdr.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID

where pa.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0057'
and pa.ASSET_ID = '000000000020'
and pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = '2014'
and pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = '11'

group by bu,
deptid,
assetnumber,
descr,
inservicedate,
assetcost, 
deprecmeth,
assetlife,
depr,
accumdepr;
```

Comment: Sorry....I'm just beginning with this.  What do you mean by DDL?

Answer (score 1):

The GROUP BY clause should only include the columns with which to identify rows that belong to the same group.  Since you are interested in the SUM of pdr.DEPR and pdr.DEPR_YTD, I am assuming you are interesting in the SUMs for rows that have the same bu, deptid, assetnumber, descr, inservciedate, asstecost, deprecmeth and assetlife.  The SUM(dpr.DEPR) and SUM(dpr.DEPR_YTD) is the calculation you are looking for.

To fix this, you need to remove the last two entries in your GROUP BY to look like this:

```
GROUP BY bu,
         deptid,
         assetnumber,
         descr,
         inservicedate,
         assetcost, 
         deprecmeth,
         assetlife;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That did it for me.  I can see this is going to be a slow learning curve.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer the aliases of the columns that you defined in your select, so do it like this. Also, you can't group on group functions, so the group by accumdepr didn't make much sense to begin with.

```
SELECT pa.BUSINESS_UNIT as bu,
pc.DEPTID as deptid,
pa.ASSET_ID as assetnumber,
pa.DESCR as descr,
pa.IN_SERVICE_DT as inservdate,
pc.COST as assetcost,
pb.METHOD as deprecmeth,
pb.LIFE as assetlife,
Sum(pdr.DEPR) as depr,
Sum(pdr.DEPR_YTD) as accumdepr
from PS_ASSET pa
inner join PS_COST pc on pc.ASSET_ID = pa.ASSET_ID
inner join PS_BOOK pb on pb.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID
inner join PS_DEPR_RPT pdr on pdr.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID

where pa.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0057'
and pa.ASSET_ID = '000000000020'
and pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = '2014'
and pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = '11'

group by
pa.BUSINESS_UNIT,
pc.DEPTID,
pa.ASSET_ID,
pa.DESCR,
pa.IN_SERVICE_DT,
pc.COST,
pb.METHOD,
pb.LIFE;
```

Comment: I appreciate your help with this.  Just learnign sql and I'm sure it's going to be a slow going at first.  Thanks again